# Is it common that one can use any sender address in Javax Mail API?

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am a new user of javax mail API. (javax.mail.*)

By trying out vanilla examples, it seems I can send out email from any address without authentication by setting the address using `setFrom()`

I tried this out on enterprise mail server and it works without warning.

This contradicts with my common sense that one need to login email account and then send out email from there.

Is this a commonly expected behavior of javax mail API and email server?

This is the code I used.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

    public class EmailTest {

        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;
        MimeMessage message;
        MimeMessageHelper helper;

        @Before
        public void setUp() {

            mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

            mailSender.setHost("smtp.company.com" ); //<some smtp host>

            message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);


        }

        @Test
        public void sendEmail() {

            try {

                helper.setFrom("john@company.com", "john doe");
                helper.setTo("jane@company.com");
                helper.setSubject("test subject");
                helper.setText("Test Text");

                mailSender.send(message);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Yes, that's how the SMTP protocol works. There is absolutely no need to authenticate the sender address.

Comment: It is, in fact, true that on an unsecured SMTP server, you can claim to be anyone at all. I have fond memories of playing pranks on friends in high school by spoofing emails. However, now that we are no longer in the 1990s, if you have an SMTP server that actually allows you to do this without any sort of authentication, it's probably a significant security hole... but not *your* concern (unless you are the admin), since this is how SMTP was originally designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not specific to Java. A sender address in a mail is just a field you can fill arbitrarily, no matter the technology. However, many mail servers will reject emails that you are trying to send without using your own email. Email servers that indeed allow any sender address will require some other kind of authentication

EDIT: compare to letters. When sending an old school letter (aka snail mail) you can put any address as the sender. the post office does not care as long as you pay for its delivery. In exactly the same way, the mail servers often do not care.

EDIT 2: however, you might run into legal problems if you try to impersonate or mislead someone. When you put Donald Duck as a sender, no one will care. If you put Donald Trump on it as sender, you might get sued for more money than you can imagine. This is true for snail mail and e mail.